# Filter non existant pointers in data browser

Tags: parse-platform

In the parse.com data browser, I just deleted a bunch of test users. Now I would like to delete rows from other objects, that are connected to the deleted users.

So I tried to use the parse.com filter for this object, setting the User column to 'does not exist'. It shows zero lines of result. When I change the filter to 'exists', it shows all result, including user pointers that when clicked on point to "There is no object matching the objectId."

Am I using this feature the wrong way, or is it broken? What should be the way to clear the secondary tables?

Regards, Jelmer

Answer (score 0):

You are using this the wrong way. [doesNotExist(key)](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#doesNotExist) references rows that actually have a null object. If the object is a pointer that points to a non-existant object, the pointer is not null which is why it's not being removed.

You'll need to check if the pointer points to a valid object. What you can do is check if createdAt exists for the objectId. If it does, then it's a valid pointer.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. The thing is that I have to use cloud code to find all invalid pointer. There should be a button in the data browser for this. "Filter invalid pointers".